# I got this error while Releasing an APK in google play console This APK will not be served to any users because it is completely shadowed

Tags: apk, release

[Error in google Playconsole while releasing an APK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaDtK.jpg)

I got this error while Releasing an APK in google play console I tried with different **versionCode** and **versionNmae** but nothing works. How do I fix this problem?

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaDtK.jpg" width="100%">
```